Black Screen After Start Up
I have Ubuntu installed on my Acer laptop for over a year now. I had an older version, but a while ago I got the 24.04 version. My laptop is dual boot. Today, I was using it as always. It froze and then I turned it off to restart. But when I turned it on again, and chose Ubuntu on SO selection, I got a black screen with nothing on it. The logo never appears. I don't know what could be the issue or how to solve it.

This question is similar to: My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Maybe it's a hardware issue. What happens when you try to boot from the Ubuntu live USB that you used to install Ubuntu?
